# How do I extract a keyword plus a corresponding number out of a text

Tags: text-mining

I am finding my way around in the different text mining tools, but I can't find the technique that does the following:

Extract out of the follwing advertisement texts

```
"apartment with bedrooms: 2, bathrooms: 2" 
"appartment with 2 bathrooms" 
"appartment with 2 beaufitul batrooms"
```

that these three appartments all have 2 bathrooms.

The text of the advertisement is already tokenized. What are my options now? Do I have to start writing algorotimhs like "find the word bathroom and a number just before it"? Or are there better techniques?

Comment: You can use regular expression. What operating system do you use ?

Comment: I work with Mac and R-studio

Comment: So you can use regular expression (regex) to do this. I don't know the syntax for regular expression in R.
This page can be useful : http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: Are you sure there is no other easier way? I have the feeling that I am inventing the hot water here

Comment: I don't think so, regex are very handy to looking for a pattern in a text. But, yeah it can be hard to write them